# Keep user after logIn with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavbarC } from '../components/Navbar/NavbarC'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from "../firebase";

export class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            authenticated: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('si');
                this.setState({ loading: false, authenticated: true });
            } else {
                console.log('no');
                this.setState({ loading: false, authenticated: false });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            console.log(null);
            return null;
        }

        if (!this.state.authenticated) {
            return (
                <div className="Home">
                    <NavbarC></NavbarC>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            console.log('no ha funcionado')
            return <Redirect to='/' />;
        }

    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. And I don't know why. Also I have tried with
[setPersistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence?hl=en-419)

when i logIn in the previous page, but neither.

Thanks for help.

PD: the log when I do it is:
 null
 null
 si
 no ha funcionado
 no ha funcionado

Comment: What do you want to show at the UI when `this.state.authenticated` is `true` i.e. user is _authenticated_?

Comment: by persist do you mean to pass the user object to all of your routes and save it for future as well in app ?

Comment: Yes, I want keep the user. Because now when I refresh page The user dissapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I wrote:

```
if (!this.state.authenticated)...
```

and is

```
if (this.state.authenticated)...
```

Sorry (so much time in front of computer). Now works.

Thanks for the help.